# Using .txt as inputs for c program

Tags: c, debugging

I have been trying to use an input.txt text file to input my numbers into the program in C. I am not sure how to approach this? There were some similar questions to this where they had to edit a "launch.json" file according to this website: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

I have tried clicking on Run> Add configurations but I'm not sure how to input inside here

Comment: You seem to ask, actually mix, two questions here. One about how to read values from a text file in C and one about a json file which you do not explain. Please focus on one question and [edit] to make that more clear according to [ask].

Comment: `launch.json` has nothing to do with C programming. It sounds like you have a question about a specific IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Example C code that meets your need created by me:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

int main(){
    FILE* p;
    int a[MAX];
    int* pa=a;

    p=fopen("./MyText.txt", "r");
    for(;;){
        if(fscanf(p, "%d", pa)==1){
            ++pa;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
            
    }
    fclose(p);

    for (int i=0;&a[i]<pa;i++){
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Create a textfile named "MyText.txt", in which there's a number each line. Then run the program.

For example, if this is the content of MyText.txt:

```
23
7
546
432
12
243
335
```

The program will read them from the file and print them out:

```
23
7
546
432
12
243
335
```

How this code works:

First, you need to declare a pointer of type FILE* ready to save the pointer to the file handler offered by the operating system.

Then use fopen function to open the file, which returns the pointer to the file handler.

Use fscanf function, analogue to scanf, to read in the file content. It returns 1 if it has successfully read in something. Break if it reaches the end of File.

Comment: And what if the text file has more than `MAX` integers to read?

Comment: @AdrianMole Change #define MAX 1000 to the maximum value you expect.